# Getting SOC temp linux-mainline on sun8i

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

Here is my environment:

- Mainline linux kernel 5.15.35
- OrangePi Plus 2E
- Yocto-based linux distro

What I would expect to see here is something in `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zoneX`, however the contents of `/sys/class/thermal` is empty.

I'm trying to get the thermal zones to show up such that I can retrieve the SOC temperature.

Below are some things I've tried:

Additional Kernel configs:

```
CONFIG_THERMAL=y
CONFIG_THERMAL_EMERGENCY_POWEROFF_DELAY_MS=0
CONFIG_THERMAL_HWMON=y
CONFIG_THERMAL_OF=y
CONFIG_THERMAL_WRITABLE_TRIPS=y
CONFIG_THERMAL_DEFAULT_GOV_FAIR_SHARE=y
CONFIG_THERMAL_GOV_FAIR_SHARE=y
CONFIG_THERMAL_GOV_STEP_WISE=y
CONFIG_THERMAL_GOV_BANG_BANG=y
CONFIG_CPU_THERMAL=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_THERMAL=y
CONFIG_THERMAL_MMIO=m
CONFIG_SUN8I_THERMAL=m
CONFIG_GENERIC_ADC_THERMAL=m
```

It is possible that some of these are unnecessary, but I wanted to try a lot of things. From here, I run `sudo modprobe sun8i_thermal`, it loads the module without issue, but still, `/sys/class/thermal` is empty.

Originally, I was on kernel 5.4, which didn't support the sun8i_thermal kernel module at all, but now that I'm on 5.15, it does support it.

Device Tree:
`sun8i-h3-orangepi-plus2e.dts`

I haven't made any changes to the standard device tree provided for this board. I suspect, I might need to for this. But I'm not quite sure where to go with that.

Would appreciate some help on this where to go from here on this. Thanks

Update 11/21:
So, I updated the default device tree with the following patch:

```
diff --git a/arch/arm/boot/dts/sun8i-h3.dtsi b/arch/arm/boot/dts/sun8i-h3.dtsi
index ae4f933ab..4e642df08 100644
--- a/arch/arm/boot/dts/sun8i-h3.dtsi
+++ b/arch/arm/boot/dts/sun8i-h3.dtsi
@@ -230,8 +230,8 @@ mali: gpu@1c40000 {
 
                ths: thermal-sensor@1c25000 {
                        compatible = "allwinner,sun8i-h3-ths";
-                       reg = <0x01c25000 0x400>;
-                       interrupts = <GIC_SPI 31 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>;
+                       reg = <0x01c25000 0x400>,<0x01c14234 0x4>;
+                       interrupts = <GIC_SPI 63 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>;
                        resets = <&ccu RST_BUS_THS>;
                        clocks = <&ccu CLK_BUS_THS>, <&ccu CLK_THS>;
                        clock-names = "bus", "mod";
```

I came up with this patch by looking at the sun8i_ths driver that used to be supported in the kernel. It came with a different example dts file with some clear differences in areas that shouldn't be different considering this is for the same board.

After that change, `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp` shows up. However, when I try to read the temp, I get the following:

```
# cat temp 
cat: temp: Invalid argument
```

Additionally, I get the following dmesg output when I grep for thermal:

```
[    0.044283] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'fair_share'
[    0.044293] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'bang_bang'
[    0.044315] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'step_wise'
[  152.544779] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 2396 at drivers/thermal/thermal_core.c:496 thermal_zone_device_update.part.0+0x284/0x2a4
[  152.555818] 'thermal_zone_device_update' must not be called without 'get_temp' ops set
[  152.563825] Modules linked in: tun cfg80211 ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_multiport xt_conntrack xt_comment iptable_filter iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c ip_tables x_tables sun8i_thermal fuse autofs4
[  152.625873] [<c079c04c>] (warn_slowpath_fmt) from [<c05b65c0>] (thermal_zone_device_update.part.0+0x284/0x2a4)
[  152.635910] [<c05b65c0>] (thermal_zone_device_update.part.0) from [<c05b67e0>] (thermal_zone_device_set_mode+0x88/0xb0)
[  152.646726] [<c05b67e0>] (thermal_zone_device_set_mode) from [<c05b7a8c>] (mode_store+0x6c/0x70)
```

This seems to indicate to me that there is a bug with the sun8i_thermal driver in the kernel

Comment: "*I haven't made any changes to the standard device tree ...*" -- The kernel config changes you made only affects the building of source code. The execution (i.e. probe & init) of device drivers is controlled by entries/nodes in the Device Tree. So you may have the necessary drivers in the kernel, but they will not be executed. Check **Documentation/devicetree/bindings/thermal/** for help.

Comment: @sawdust those entries for thermal zones and thermal sensors exist in the dts already

Comment: Does the `probe()` function of your driver execute correctly?  Have you tried sprinkling it with debug messages?  There should be an `of_device_id` struct near the bottom of your driver, and one of those `.compatible` strings should match one of the ones in your `.dts` file.